# Xamarin iOS10.2 app crashes on photo upload

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ios10.2

I am using Xamarin cross platform solution to build the iOS 10.2 apps. 
The app crashes while trying to upload photo. It does when the app is built on 8.2 but after upgrading to 10.2 it crashes. I have tried all the privacy setting recommended by Xamarin https://blog.xamarin.com/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/. I have included the settings for photo library, camera, media etc but nothing seems to be resolving the issue.

Additionally, the app does provide the option to select photo library or icloud but it crashes right after that on selecting either of them or clicking back in the app.

Comment: Are there any error messages? In the output window, anything? And what did you add for the new privacy settings?

Comment: I am not getting any details about the crash in the logs. These are all the privacy permission settings that I have used:
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires photo use</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires camera use</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires location use</string>
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires contact use</string>
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires media library use</string>